# How do you fire forge.ajax periodically in Trigger.io app?

Tags: ajax, trigger.io

Does anyone have an example of how to fire forge.ajax periodically in a Trigger.io app?  It seems to fire once, then die silently.  Is Trigger.io removing the setTimeout or stopping it?   I'm using this technique adapted from Paul Irish.

```
// Wrap this function in a closure so we don't pollute the namespace
(function worker() {
  forge.request.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/test.html', 
    complete: function() {
      // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
      setTimeout(worker, 5000);
    }
  });
})();
```

Could it be a scope issue perhaps?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: It's a scope issue.  If I move the setTimeout outside of the complete callback, then it fires.

Comment: If you just want to call it once after 5 seconds then the timeout will work but if you want to call it every 5 seconds you will need to use setInterval this will call your function every X seconds etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `forge.request.ajax` is similiar to `jQuery.ajax` it is not the same, and it has no complete callback.

You probably want to put your `setTimeout` in both the `success` and `error` callbacks.